# Nested inline-block elment div

Tags: html, css, angular

i try a grid with display:inline-block with divs.
When I positioning the divs next to next all works fine.
When I try to set elements inside the div then the parent div move down:
[image: error]

The code:

```html
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <div *ngFor="let xUnit of xUnits; let i=index"
        style="width: 106px;
              max-width: 106px;
              display:inline-block;
              position: relative;
              height: 50px;
              max-height: 50px;
              padding-right: 5px;
              border: 1px solid #e5e7eb">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of getItems(resources[0], xUnit)">
        <div style="height: 25px;
                  position: relative;
                  border-left: 2px solid #FA607E;
                  background: white;
                  margin-left: 5px;
                  display: block;
                  margin-right: 5px;
                  color: #FA607E;
                  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
                  font-weight: 300;"
            [style.width]="getWidth(item)">
          <span style="padding-left: 5px;">
            Test
          </span>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try vertical-align:top to all your inline-block elements

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the biggest so called 'bugs' in `inline-block` (alongside with crazy `2px` extra space that it will add to elements!)

It happens because browser now sees your divisions as text! And is trying to align them based on their `baseline`

In most cases setting

`vertical-align: top;`
Solves the problem

however
**I Recommend you to use flexbox because it has complete and good options for vertical alignment of elements**